# If Toggle Enabled, Display EMA50

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

have a very simple script and I'm just trying to enable a toggle and cant seem to get it to work.

Heres the toggle

```
toggleEma50 = input.bool(true, title = "EMA50", group=g1)
```

Heres the working EMA50 pinescript:

```
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
plot(ema50, color=#3179f5, title='EMA50: ', linewidth=1)
```

**What I've Tried so far**

Attempt 1: (Error:line 381: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.)

```
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
if toggleEma50
    plot(ema50, color=#3179f5, title='EMA50: ', linewidth=1)
```

Attempt 2: (Error: line 381: Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'series'='emaAndToggle'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected
)

```
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
emaAndToggle = ema50 and toggleEma50
plot(emaAndToggle, color=#3179f5, title='EMA50: ', linewidth=1)
```

Out of any ideas of what to try.. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your bool input in a ternary statement to set the plot to either your ema, or to na when not in use. We can make the ternary statement right in the series argument slot int the `plot()` call like this:

```
toggleEma50 = input.bool(true, title = "EMA50", group=g1)

ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
plot(toggleEma50 ? ema50 : na, color=#3179f5, title='EMA50: ', linewidth=1)
```

`plot()` can not be used in local scope, so we must manipulate the value, rather than the function itself.

Cheers and all the best

Comment: works perfectly! ive been seeing `na` in diff indicators wondering what its for.. what does it mean and where can i read more about it? thanks for the help!

Comment: not applicable, not available, not assessed, or no answer. You may also see NaN or not a number or Null etc. Its just nothing